# How does cooling scale with volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, volume

What equation would give me the answer to the question, "If i have a cup of water at a tempature of say boiling, how long would that cup of water take to cool off compared to say half that size of a cup of water."  So the volume is in half.  Its a general question I am just looking for where to start.

Comment: Sean, google for "heat transfer", to learn about basics of a very complicated field, and that this is not a part of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An actual cup is slightly complicated because there are 2–3 distinct types of surfaces. Let's deal with free-floating cubes of water instead, both at an initial temperature *T<sub>i</sub>*  in an environment with temperature *T<sub>e</sub>* .

A cube with half the volume will have 50% the thermal mass *C*, but 63% of the surface area *A*. Newton's Law of Cooling implies $\frac{dT}{dt}=-h\frac{A}{C}(T-T_0\!)$ , where *h* is a property of the environment. So the smaller cube will cool 26% faster initially, when both cubes are at *T<sub>i</sub>* .

If you want to know the temperature of a cube at any given time, the solution to the differential equation above is $\frac{T-T_e}{T_i-T_e}=\exp\left(-ht\frac{A}C\right)$. If you solve for *t*, it follows that when the small cube is at a given temperature, it will take the large cube 26% more time to reach it.

Comment: This is not wrong, but utterly misleading, because vaporizing is 99 % of heat transfer in the case of boiling water (and well below 100°C still), as asked for!

Comment: @Georg, vaporization and convection are both rolled up into the heat transfer coefficient. True, I assume that *h* is constant with temperature, but generally people aren't so anal about obvious back-of-the-envelope calculations. What's with the chip on your shoulder?

Comment: Vaporisation and convection (especially when not forced, but by Grashoff) are terribly nonlinear. To roll them up in a linear coefficient is misleading. (Especially to beginners!)

Comment: Not a physicist or even remotely scientifically literate, but I came here to ask a similar question and was directed here. Can you ELI5 this answer? Does the smaller cube or the larger cube become cooler faster?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to start by looking at [Newton's law of cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Solution_in_terms_of_object_heat_capacity).